# Loading NonZero Balance Account in to DevExpress Tree list

Tags: c#, .net, list, tree, devexpress

I would like to load the Non-zero account balance of parent child relation.
if the child balance is >0 need to display the respective details with its parent and  nested parent.
I Need to display the Nonzero account balance of the child with its parent.
the relation is nested
So please i need a help over this issue.
I'm using DevExpress Tree List.

**Here is my code for populating the Account in tree**

```
private void populateTree(Account account, TreeListNode parentNode)
{       
    Account[] children = account.children;
    if (account.header == "True")
    {
        TreeListNode currentNode = addNode(account, parentNode);
        foreach (Account childAccount in children)
        {
            populateTree(childAccount, currentNode);
        }
    }
    else if (account.header == "False" && account.currentBalance > 0)
    {
        TreeListNode currentNode = addNode(account, parentNode);                             
    }
}
```

**My Screen-Shot.**
[image]

**My-Tree View**
[image: **My-Tree View**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at the link
**[`Loading NonZero Balance Account in to DevExpress Tree list`](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q565136)**

Answer (score 1):

Using this method, you will be able to witch account as a non zero sub account balance.

```
public bool IsAcountOrSubAccountNonZeroBalance(Account account)
{
    if (account.currentBalance > 0)
    return true;
    foreach (var child in account.children)
    {
        if (IsAcountOrSubAccountNonZeroBalance(child))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

On your screen shot, the red stripped account would return false.

You can add this method to your previous logic like this

```
else if (account.header == "False" && IsAcountOrSubAccountNonZeroBalance(account))
{
    TreeListNode currentNode = addNode(account, parentNode);                             
}
```